# Distance measurements missing when placing item in design view of android studio. How do I activate it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Here's a link to what I need (in Android Studio 1.0):

[image: Distances between widgets shown]

When I place a widget in Android Studio 2.2.2, the encircled information window is missing. Any idea how I can activate it? I'd really like to see the distances between widgets while placing them.

Comment: what android studio version and what JDK are you using?

Comment: @piotrek1543 I'm using the latest Android studio 2.2.2 and the latest JDK.